# Как программно кликнуть на элементе?

Tags: jquery

Добрый день.
Как программно кликнуть на элементе, id которого будет известен в процессе работы приложения?
Например, мне надо кликнуть на элементе `$("#Vopros32").click();`.
А как подставить число в id вместо 32? 
Спасибо.

Comment: а в чем проблема-то? Сложите две строки внутри селектора, где первая строка, скажем ""#Vopros", а вторая - некое число (32 или любое другое)

Comment: Думаю, корректнее использовать что-то вроде класса, скажем, `js-questions`, и искать его по индексу, т.е. `$('.js-questions').eq(32).trigger('click');`, плодить ID для множества элементов плохая практика ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@DreamChild, @Олег Б, думаю нужно объединить ваши мысли:

```
$("#Vopros" + id).trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var id = 32;
$("#Vopros" + id).trigger('click');
```